# Clone checkbox append and if check one the other uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make checkbox as radio but I not used radio I must be used checkbox but when I append checkbox it does not work as radio, plz how to set after appending checkbox as a radio,
code.

```js
jQuery(function($){

  $(".add").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var main_div = $('.append');
      var new_offer = $("li:last", main_div).clone();
  new_offer.appendTo(main_div);
        
    });


   $('input.check_one').on('change', function() {
      $('input.check_one').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="append">
<ul>
<li>
 
 <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key]" class="check_one">

</li>
</ul>
</div>
 <button class="add">add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend you to stick to radio, However use event delegation for dynamic elements  `$('.append').on('change', 'input.check_one', function() {
    $('input.check_one').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the way you attach event listener

```js
jQuery(function($){

  $(".add").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var main_div = $('.append');
      var new_offer = $("li:last", main_div).clone().prop('checked',false);
  new_offer.appendTo(main_div);
        
    });


   $('.append').on('change','input.check_one', function() {
      $('input.check_one').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="append">
<ul>
<li>
 
 <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key]" class="check_one">

</li>
</ul>
</div>
 <button class="add">add</button>
</body>
</html>
```